# reload a specific section of a web page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Please I'm working with php, ajax and jquery. when I post a status the status is posted with ajax and php, so no entire page reloading happens, but the problem is I want the posted status to be viewed along side the already posted status which means that the old status need to  be refreshed so the new posted status appear with me....I wish I could do that and update only the status section without the whole page...this is the code I use to Post the status without reloading.

```js
$('input#post-submit').on('click', function(){  
     var post = $('textarea#userPost').val();
     var azoul = $('input#token').val();  
     if($.trim(post) != '' && $.trim(azoul) === 'azoul_majidi15AJH45skLD')  
     {  
         $.ajax({    
         url:"post-post.php",
         method:"POST",
         data:{post:post,azoul},`enter code here`
         dataType:"text",
         success:function(data){ 
                   $('#post-state').text('Your Status was posted successfully'); 
                }
          });
     }  
});
```

Comment: in the success callback, use $.load() https://api.jquery.com/load/ with a page fragment part. or use json to build your dom

Comment: you can use jquery to update the corresponding status section html. Without the html detail, I cant provide a code to show how to do it. But usually you can just select the corresponding DOM element and change the class or text value or some color of it. You can even empty the whole part and re-construct the html string then append to it.

Comment: Thank you @user3089009 , I'll try that out ;) thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the success of your ajax, replace the html of your old post div with new post content. `$("#old_post_div").html("new_post_content");`
Or you can use prepend or append so that the new content will be prepended or appended along with old content.

Comment: That looks both easy and effective. thank you Mr @Kishor Malakar.